# Вычисление выражения

Tags: c++

> Calculate the expression:
>   1/a +1/(a+1) +..+ 1/((a+1)...(a + n))
>
> Example:
>   Input:
>    2 1
>   Output:
>    0.666667
>
> Example:
>   Input:
>    2.1 2
>   Output:
>    0.667266

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, i;
    double a = 0, s, d;
    cin >> a >> n;
    s = 1.0 / a;
    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        a = a * (a + i);
        s = s + 1.0 / a;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Не могли бы вы помочь найти, где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    double a, s;
    cin >> a >> n;
    s = 1.0/a;
    a = a + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        s = s + (1.0 / a);
        a = a * (a + i);
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Just_kiss_me, я исправил свой ответ, тот код, на который вы ответили работал неверно.

Answer (score 1):

У вас формула должна быть по условию

1/a + 1(a+1) + 1/(a+1)(a+2) + ... + 1/(a+1)...(a+n), неправда ли?

У вас же цикл строит, щоб не соврать

1/a + 1/а(a+1) + 1/а(a+1)(a+2) + ... + 1/а(a+1)...(a+n)

Проблема в том, что 0.(6) (ну 0.666667) в данном алгоритме при а=2 n=1 получаем как раз в том виде, который написали вы.

Если приводить к схеме, то код выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n = 0, i;
    double a = 0, s, d;

    cin >> a >> n;
    d = 1;          // !
    s = 1.0 / a;
    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        d = d * (a + i); // !
        s = s + 1.0 / d; // !
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот правильный. Нашел причину:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    double a, d = 0, c = 1;
    cin >> a >> n;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        c = c * (a + i);
        d = d + 1.0 / c;
    }
    cout << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```